# evaluation of when condition in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook that uses multiple hostgroup like (appserver,app01server,dbserver,db01server) and if the hostgroup contains db* then the condition should execute. I have written something like this :

```
- name: status of the app
  shell: echo "Hello World"
  when: ansible_host == "db*"
```

What regex pattern should be used or how to use a regex here ?

Answer (score 0):

Try **db\w+**

```
- name: status of the app
  shell: echo "Hello World"
  when: ansible_host == "db\w+"
```

You can test with [regex101](https://regex101.com/) .